# RecyclerView isn't fixed to top when Items are added

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have this RecyclerView that doesn't want to show the item at position 0 anymore, after enough items are added to make the RecyclerView scrollable. Instead it seems to stick to the bottom item and scroll down with this one, although the other items are added at position 0.

```
public class hauptseite extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ImageButton btnInput;
private EditText editTextInput;
private int position = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btnInput = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.name_add);

    createExampleList();
    buildRecyclerView();

    btnInput = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.name_add);

    btnInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = editTextInput.getText().toString();
            insertItem(name);
        }
    });
}

public void insertItem(String name) {
    mExampleList.add(position, new ExampleItem(name));
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
    editTextInput.setText("");
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    mExampleList.remove(position);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void createExampleList() {
    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void buildRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerName);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

   mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
       @Override
    public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
        removeItem(position);
    }
    });
}
```

And the adapter

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onDeleteClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public ImageView mDeleteName;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_added);
        mDeleteName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_name);

        mDeleteName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onDeleteClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
    mExampleList = exampleList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
    ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getName1());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}
```

So what do I need change when I want my RecyclerView to stay at the item in position 0 unless I start scrolling down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to the desired position on the insert:

```
mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(yourPosition)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is easy way to fix that.
do not add item at position 0 ... just reverse the default order of your recyclerView

```
 LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
            linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two good ways of solving this:

One: Don't hold position in your activity, but use the size of the `ArrayList`

```
public void insertItem(String name) {
    mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(name));
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mExampleList.size() - 1);
    editTextInput.setText("");
}
```

Two: Move the example list and its methods into your adapter. This way you can also remove the interface for deletion and let the adapter handle it all. I also added a method to retrieve the current list of items from the adapter incase you need that data outside of the adapter.

Activity:

```
public class hauptseite extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ImageButton btnInput;
private EditText editTextInput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btnInput = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.name_add);

    buildRecyclerView();

    btnInput = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.name_add);

    btnInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = editTextInput.getText().toString();
            mAdapter.insertItem(name);
        }
    });
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void createExampleList() {
    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void buildRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerName);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter();

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

And the adapter:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

public insertItem(String name) {
   mExampleList.add(name);
   this.notifyItemAdded(mExampleList.size() -1)
}

public removeItem(int position) {
   mExampleList.remove(position);
   this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public ArrayList<ExampleItems> getItems() {
  return mExampleList();
}

public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mTextView1;
    public ImageView mDeleteName;

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_added);
        mDeleteName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_name);

        mDeleteName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        removeItem(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public ExampleAdapter() {
    mExampleList = new ExampleList();
}
```